# Latex inserts blank line AND indents new paragraph

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs

I'm very new with LaTeX. My setup is as follows:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%the above just for the case that it is relevant to the problem

\section{Introduction}

FIRST PARAGRAPH

SECOND PARAGRAPH

THIRD PARAGRAPH

Nth PARAGRAPH

\section{Next-Section}
```

Between each paragraph I got just one blank line. Let every paragraph be the sentence "Nth blue bird." The problem now is that the output is formatted like so:

```
First blue bird
    Second blue bird

    Third blue bird

    Nth blue bird.
```

I.e. the second paragraph is just indented as I want it to be. But every consecutive paragraph is not only indented but also has a blank line inserted before.

Note that if I shorten the third paragraph the problem vanishes. (I did not check though if shortening of other paragraphs yields the same result).

Any idea? (Impeding deadline; Quick help is highly appreciated)

Comment: Try adding `\raggedbottom` to the preamble.

Comment: It worked perfectly. If you mind post it as answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain equivalent questions have been asked before, but if I can't find a duplicate I'll post an answer.